# Returning two parts of a list as a pair

Tags: scheme

In my program, I am supposed to write a function where it splits a list into even and odd. The problem is that the output/syntax is incorrect. I am getting `((1 3) (2 4))` when testing out the example `(split '(1 2 3 4))`. The output needs to look like `((1 3) 2 4)`

Here is my code:

```
(define (split l)
  (define (odd l)
    (if (null? l) '()
        (if (null? (cdr l)) (list (car l))
            (cons (car l) (odd (cddr l))))))
  (define (even l)
    (if (null? l) '()
        (if (null? (cdr l)) '()
            (cons (cadr l) (even (cddr l))))))
  (cons (odd l) (cons (even l) '())))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`(even l)` is already a list. You don't need to wrap it in an extra cons.
The code  below should work.

```
(define (split l)
  (define (odd l)
    (if (null? l) '()
        (if (null? (cdr l)) (list (car l))
            (cons (car l) (odd (cddr l))))))
  (define (even l)
    (if (null? l) '()
        (if (null? (cdr l)) '()
            (cons (cadr l) (even (cddr l))))))
  (cons (odd l) (even l)))
```